# Open ms word/excel applications without using activeXObject for cross browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

```
var sPath = ProChild.GetProperty("File Location");  
var sMacro = ProChild.GetProperty("Excel Macro To Run");
```

//would like to modify following code without using activeXObject

```
 if(sMacro != null && sMacro ==""){  
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");   
    oShell.Run(sPath);
```

**New code for better understanding**

```
function OpenFile(){  
alert ('Work');  
//would like to modify ActiveXObject with any other object for cross-browser. 
var x = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");  
x.run('winword.exe');  
}  
//Above code works only in IE. But don't want to use activeXObject. 
//Is there any possibility to open a word file in Internet Explorer 
//without using activexobject. Request for a solution.
```

Comment: Modify how? For what purpose? What are you trying to accomplish? Please elaborate. Your question was marked for the Low Quality Posts review queue and is likely to be closed if you don't provide further detail.

Comment: ActiveXObject will not support in Siebel open UI. Is there any way to modify same code without using activeXObject ( Because activeXObject is only for IE, would request cross-browser fix using jquery/ajax ). Purpose is no longer support activeX in Siebel open UI ( plz. see 39 page in the mentioned link, for more info on activex http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/PDF/config_open_ui.pdf ). Finally I would like to achieve opening a simple word/xml file without using activeX. Please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Comment: Above code works only in IE. But don't want to use activeXObject. Is there any possibility to open a word/exel file in Internet Explorer without using activexobject. Request for a solution

Comment: Using Word in IE or another browser depends on a lot of things, such as whether the client actually has Word or Excel installed, which version, which browser etc.  You could set the MIME types on the server which will allow viewing/editing, but then you have issues with DEP and so on.

Comment: Thanks Westie for your suggestion.

Comment: Any more suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this sometime back but then this is not actually that easy, there is whole set of functionality that comes up with an application like Excel/Word.

Ultimately displaying excel or word on client machine is a mess, I tried and got stuck in executing macros.

There is nothing to my knowledge that would allow word/excel to be given in all the browser, even AcitveX objects wont let you use most of the functionlity.

Try find some other solution if possible, I has to display a PremiumCalculator excel in webpage instead of letting people download the same, I went ahead and created a PremiumCalculator in asp.net, instead of displaying the existing sheet in web browser.

Comment: Thanks Vijay Pandey for spending your precious time. Please let me know if there are any possibilities to open word/excel file only on IE ( Without using activeX )

Comment: Any more suggestions would be helpful

Comment: You can convert it to google doc and embed in your website if that is possible for you, if your doc is having macros/buttons and etc it wont work. Why dont you let him download and use the same?